# RDS connection broker: unable to resolve .local address over VPN for session hosts

Tags: vpn, rds

I deployed an RDS collection using a 1 connection broker and 2 session host servers. These are on a .local domain on a private network which has its own DNS. When I'm on the network, I connect to the connection broker and I'm able to successfullyresolve rds1.domain.local and connect to one of these session host servers.

The problem is when I connect to the company network over VPN. The VPN connection is to the company wide network, which routs to our internal IP's. However, the problem is that I'm forced to use the DNS servers for the VPN connection which do not resolve my domain.local addresses on my DNS server. I cannot seem to override this even if i specify DNS IP's in the network cards.

So i'm connected over VPN, i connect to the connection broker which redirects me to a session host, but my PC cannot resolve the host name rds1.domain.local (fictitious name, but you get the idea). The only workaround I found is to put these hosts and IP's in my local host file.

I can't think of a way to get around this problem

Comment: If the VPN connects you to the corporate network why isn't it assigning you corporate DNS servers? That seems like a misconfiguration of the VPN to me.

Comment: The DNS servers are set to the main network DNS, but we have our own AD infrastructure on a private segment. VPN is configured correctly, we just have a less than ideal setup.

Comment: Can you get the party that manages the main DNS to set up conditional forwarders for your ".local" domain?